# What is $E\left[\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{3}\right]$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

We all know $E\left[\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}\right] = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^{2} = \frac{n-1}{n}E\left[\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}\right]$ where $\overline{X}$ is the average of a sample with size $n$ that includes $X_{i}$.

Can $E\left[\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{3}\right]$ be nicely written in terms of $E\left[\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)^{3}\right]$? If so, what is that formula?

This is not as easy as I thought it would be.

Comment: What are $X$ and $\bar{X}$? Did you mean $E[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2] = \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma^2$ in the first line?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the binomial?

Comment: @angryavian Oh, $X$ is just a random variable and $\overline{X}$ is the average from a sample. I really should have written $X_{i}$. For your second comment, $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}] = E[(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}]$. We're saying the same thing, I just lazily dropped the sub i.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The problem with expanding the binomial is that you get nasty terms like $E[3X_{i}\overline{X}^{2}]$. I was hoping there would be a shorter way to avoid that step. Also, I don't need a proof, so I was just hoping that someone would drop an answer without explanation lol

Comment: @DavisParks It is important that the $X_i$ (your $X$) is one of the elements of the sample used to compute $\bar{X}$ (rather than an independent copy outside the sample), which isn't clear from your problem statement. But I understand what you mean now.

Comment: @DavisParks Notice that you can take the $\bar X^2$ out of the expectation so the computation is rather simple.

Comment: @angryavian Yeah, I totally understand. I'll go back and fix the question. Lazy short-handing came back to bite!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is also random.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I may have thrown you off with my lazy notation (it's fixed now). $\overline{X}$ is the average of a sample including $X_{i}$ (where all the elements are iid). In the case of $E[(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}]$, you have a term with $E[X_{i} \cdot \overline{X}] = \mu^{2} + \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}$ since $\overline{X}$ and $X_{i}$ are correlated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261400/21801) which cites [page 7 of this document](https://modelingwithdata.org/pdfs/moments.pdf), $$E[(X_i - \bar{X})^3] = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2} E[(X_i-\mu)^3].$$
Proving this amounts to expanding $(X_i - \bar{X})^3$ and doing a bit of accounting for each term.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I expected it to be, but I couldn't find confirmation of this anywhere when I looked. You are a life saver.